# Prevent evenListener when input is in focus

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a few keybinds set up in my script but **when my focus is on an input field I don't want them to trigger**. I've already tried removeEventListener() but could not quite get it to work the way I want it to.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.code == "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleHiddenElements();
  }
  else if (e.code == "KeyA") {
    toggleScene("vorspann");
  }
  else if (e.code == "KeyE") {
    toggleScene("abspann");
  }
  else if (e.code == "KeyL") {
    loadSetup();
  }
  else if (e.code == "KeyR") {
    resetUI();
  }
});
```

And this is one of the input fields for example:

```
<input type="text" id="vorspann-thema" placeholder="Enter a title">
```

The easiest solution would be to use binds that you don't normally need like the F-keys but sadly they have to be A, E, L, R and Enter.

Following proposal did not work:

```
var speakerfocus = false;

function getfocus(e) {
  speakerfocus = true;
  console.log(speakerfocus);
}

document.getElementById("speakers-schmal").addEventListener("click", getfocus);

document.addEventListener('click', removefocus);

function removefocus(e) {
  if (e.target != document.getElementById("bauchbinde-schmal")) {
    speakerfocus = false;
    console.log(speakerfocus);
    return;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to my problem with the help of expressjs123.

In order for the code to work for all of my input tags I had to use **getElementsByTagName** which creates a list of all my input tags which I then iterated with a for-loop.

Setting an **eventListener for "click" so focus equals true** and **one for 'blur' so focus equals false** when leaving an input field.

An example can be viewed here!

```js
let focus = false;
let inputList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (let i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
  inputList[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    focus = true;
  })
  inputList[i].addEventListener('blur', () => {
    focus = false;
  })
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (focus == false) {
    if (e.code == "KeyR") {
      redBGcolor();
    } else if (e.code == "KeyG") {
      greenBGcolor();
    }
  }
})

function redBGcolor() {
  document.getElementById("bod").classList.add('red');
  document.getElementById("bod").classList.remove('green');
}

function greenBGcolor() {
  document.getElementById("bod").classList.add('green');
  document.getElementById("bod").classList.remove('red');
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

input {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body id='bod'>

  <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="text" id="mname"><br>
  <input type="text" id="tname"><br>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean flag that determines whether the input is in focus. Add a click event listener to the input, and if the flag is true, then change it to false, otherwise change it to true. Then you can use a if statement in your keybinding.

```js
let focus = false;
document.getElementById('vorspann-thema').addEventListener('click', () => {
focus = true;
});
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
if (e.target != document.getElementById('vorspann-thema') focus = false;
});
```

Comment: So I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work for me. The keybinds stopped working altogether. Check my updated questions for the code I wrote.

Comment: You need to use either `==` or `===` in your conditional statement - you put `if (speakerfocus=false)` which is invalid js code because you're assigning in the if statement. Change `=` to either `==` or `===`

Comment: Ah dumb mistake on my side, just fixed it.

It however still doesn't work. Before clicking the input box once all the keybinds work but speakerfocus does not turn to false once input loses focus.

Comment: Now I edited it so that when you click out of the input box, the focus will become false

Comment: I updated my code above, still doesn't work sadly. Clicking on input will trigger getfocus as well as remove focus somehow.